# mypy error: List or tuple literal expected as the second argument to namedtuple()

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I wrote this code in Python 3.5:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

attributes = ('content', 'status')
Response = namedtuple('Response', attributes)
```

When I run the Mypy type checker to analyze this code it raised the error:

> error: List or tuple literal expected as the second argument to `namedtuple()`

I tried to add a type annotation to the `attributes` variable:

```py
from typing import Tuple
attributes = ('content', 'status')  # type: Tuple[str, str]
```

But it didn't fix the raised error.

Comment: Looks like an issue with mypy because the namedtuple is fine as-is.  Try unpacking the tuple, for instance... `a, b = Response('some content', 'some attr')` --> `print('%s; %s' % (a, b))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want mypy to understand what your namedtuples look like, you should import `NamedTuple` from the `typing` module, like so:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

Response = NamedTuple('Response', [('content', str), ('status', str)])
```

Then, you can use `Response` just like any other namedtuple, except that mypy now understands the types of each individual field. If you're using Python 3.6, you can also use the alternative class-based syntax:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Response(NamedTuple):
    content: str
    status: str
```

If you were hoping to dynamically vary the fields and write something that can "build" different namedtuples at runtime, that's unfortunately not possible within Python's type ecosystem. PEP 484 currently doesn't any provisions for propagating or extracting the actual *values* of any given variable during the type-checking phase.

It's actually pretty challenging to implement this in a fully general way, so it's unlikely this feature will be added any time soon (and if it is, it'll likely be in a much more limited form).

Comment: That Python 3.6 syntax is too beautiful, though.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard -- That might actually be more of a thing in the future! Guido is apparently interested in modifying Python itself so you can define custom classes in that style (without all of the namedtuple overhead, and without having to write an `__init__` method) -- see [this post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2017-May/045654.html) from the python-ideas mailing list, and some of the follow-up ones. The discussion was partially inspired by the [attrs library](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs), which is evidently pretty popular.

Comment: Ah, I remember seeing that thread. With 50+ replies though (if I remember correctly), I never got to follow it thoroughly. Since I haven't seen a post for the PEP draft I guess we're waiting for that, now :-)

Comment: Thanks! great answer :)

Answer (score 4):

According to [issue 848](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/848) on `mypy`'s issue tracker, this will just never be implemented (see last message by GvR).

Though `# type: ignore` does actually silence this warning it then creates other issues, so, if you can, don't depend on dynamically specifying the field names of the namedtuple (i.e provide the literal in the ways Michael's answer provides).